# How to implement auto-updating iOS Apps from App Store?

Tags: ios

How the old release communicate with App Store, and find a new release is available? I have no idea on this issue.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. App upgrading is managed by the App Store, in other words, the system.

Comment: I've had this problem for a while myself. I released this little tool called [**Harpy**](https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Harpy) that checks the installed version against the App Store version. If a newer version is available in the store, it notifies your end-user and prompts them to download the app when your application launches. [**Grab it on Github**](https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Harpy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App updates are handled by the OS. The user is notified of updates for your app when they become available. They have the option to update. Thus, you cannot update in secret.

Your app could utilize an external server for a portion of its functionality, achieving the same result in some cases.

You could also notify the user of available updates when your app is run.

Comment: Yup, some of the Zynga apps let you know when they can be updated. That should be fine.